# How can I fix patch error of android studio 2.2

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.3

I am on Android studio 2.2.

Now android studio 2.3 is released. But Clicking update and restart, after download complete it show this error

android studio 2.3 update error message

[image]

How can i fix this?

Comment: I have same problem.
I am thinking its because of permission for user.
Because I am not admin on my computer.

Comment: I am admin on my computer